# Add label to the data

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggspatial

Hi I would like to plot a map section from the N Atlantic with this code! Therefore I use this code.

```
library(ggOceanMaps)
library(readxl)
library(ggspatial)
library(dplyr)

data_a <- structure(list(
  Nr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Name = c(
    "MD95-2006",
    "IODP 302", "IODP 302", "IODP 302", "IODP 302", "IODP 302"
  ),
  Lat = c(57.083333, 87.89, 87.9036, 87.92118, 87.93333, 87.86658), Long = c(
    -8.05, 137.65, 138.46065, 139.365501, 139.535,
    136.17735
  )
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data_b <- structure(list(Nr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Name = c("Simstich", 
"Schiebel", "Schiebel", "Stangeew", "Stangeew", "Stangeew"), 
    Lat = c(75.003333, 62.50275, 67.225033, 56.2747, 53.4347, 
    52.874), Long = c(-7.313333, -13.99235, 2.920317, -48.6992, 
    -50.0673, -51.5128)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

data <- bind_rows(list(data_a,data_b), .id="data_source")


map <- basemap(limits = c(-60, -35, 62, 57), glaciers = TRUE,shapefiles = "Arctic",   bathy.style = "rcb") +
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_point(
    data = data, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, color = data_source)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("red", "yellow")
  ) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)))
print(map)
```

Now I want to set the information Name = c("...") to the data points. How can I achieve this? The labels should not have a white border and should not be in a box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggspatial::geom_spatial_text(_repel)` to add your labels. In the code below I opted for `_repel` as it automatically shifts the labels to avoid overlapping labels and labels overlapping the data points:

```
library(ggOceanMaps)
library(ggspatial)
library(ggrepel)

basemap(limits = 40, glaciers = TRUE, shapefiles = "Arctic", bathy.style = "rcb") +
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_point(
    data = data, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, color = data_source)
  ) +
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_text_repel(
    data = data, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, label = Name)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("red", "yellow")
  ) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but when I use this there is the error message: there is no package ‘ggrepel’. What can I dO?

Comment: Try `install.packages("ggrepel")`.

Comment: Nice ok maby add this to your answer :D But thanks a lot! Have a nice week :D

Comment: And is there also a possibility to change the size?

Comment: Of course. You can set the fontsize via `size=`, e.g. `geom_spatial_text_repel(
    data = data, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, label = Name), size = 5
  )`. The size is measured in `mm`. If you want to set the font size in points then you can convert using `.pt`, e.g. size = 8 / .pt. The default size is approx. 11 points or 3.88

Comment: I tryed one more thing: geom_spatial_text_repel(     data = data, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, label = Name), size = 5, color=white   ). With this code i wanna give the labels a transparent white background of the lables and I also want to bring the labels infornt of the lat and long lines so it looks more mature. However my try didnt work do you have an answer to this?

Comment: Or do you have a nice page were I can search this type of questions? I didn´t finde any

Comment: If you want a background use `geom_spatial_label(_repel)`, e.g. `ggspatial::geom_spatial_label_repel(..., fill = "white", label.size = NA)`.

Comment: thanks for your very fast answer, I also tryed this but it gives me the error:  Ignoring unknown parameters: `fill` and `label.size`

Comment: Hm. That sounds as if you are still using `_text_` instead of `_label_`. `ggspatial::geom_spatial_label_repel(data = data, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, label = Name), fill = "white", label.size = NA)` works fine for me.

Comment: OMG I feel so sorry!! Thank you so much :D. However How can I set the lat long lines in the back. I update my question! However thank you already you saved my day :D

Comment: Use `+ theme(panel.ontop = FALSE)`.